# Discord js doesn't plays audio anymore

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I had a base discordjs code that could play 2 audio files, leave and join voice channels, but I did created a new file with this code followed from a youtube video:

```
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    descreption: 'Play',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) return message.send('PALI! Egy voice channelben bent kéne lenne, már nemazé!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('Player')) return message.reply('Kéne rang is nem gondolnád?, hogy a bánat egyeki a lelked!');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.reply('KÖZÖLDNÉDHOGYMIAKUKITAKARSZ?? (Need more argumets)');

        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        }
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
        if (video) {
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
            connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 100 })
            on('finish', () => {
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });

            await message.reply(`Most játszom: ***${video.title}$***`)
        }
        else {
            message.channel.send('Nem találtam videót.')
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to imploment it into my other js file, but after I did it it gave me errors so I gave it up and deleted all that stuff, but now the original code just doesn't wants to play audio, it doesn't gives me errors or anything, I tried everthing I could but I couldn't solve it. Any solutions?
Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
//const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
//const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
var prefix = ';';
client.login('CENSORED');

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('\n ----------WELCOME TO ADY STUDIOS AUTOMATIC------------')
})

client.on('message', async message => {
    
  if (message.content === ';join') {
    
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();   
       
    } else {
      message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
  }
  if(message.content === ';leave'){
    message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();  
    }

   if (message.content === ';coconut') {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.play('./coconut.m4a');
   }
   if (message.content === ';roll'){
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
       const dispatcher = connection.play('./rickroll.m4a');
   }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

{   "dependencies": {     "@discordjs/opus": "^0.3.2",     "discord.js": "^12.3.1",     "ffmpeg-static": "^4.2.7",     "mysql": "^2.18.1",     "opusscript": "0.0.7",     "request": "^2.88.2",     "ytdl-core": "^4.2.1"   } } install disc should be work

Comment: Please explain your answer more thoroughly. What are you adding? How are you adding it? Why does this fix OPs issue?

Comment: I dont really understand can you please explain it?